# how to use a selectbox to fetch data from database row symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, twig

I am currently working with a small project in symfony2. I have made a simple table with crud command. I have a entity called "voorraad"(=stock) that has a association with entity "product" and the entity "Locatie"(=Location). How it works: I can add a product and location to my stock.

So my problem, is that I cant figure out how to display the products in my stock by location with a selectbox. The idea is to have a selectbox with the locations from my location entity, and If I select a option that it will only show the products of my option. Below my code:

Controller

```
<?php

 namespace ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
 use ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Entity\Voorraad;
 use ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Form\VoorraadType;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * Voorraad controller.
 *
 * @Route("/voorraad")
 */
class VoorraadController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Voorraad entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="voorraad")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->findBy(array(), array('locatie'=>'asc'));

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
/**
 * Creates a new Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="voorraad_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Voorraad();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @param Voorraad $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Voorraad $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new VoorraadType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('voorraad_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="voorraad_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Voorraad();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="voorraad_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Voorraad entity.
*
* @param Voorraad $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Voorraad $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new VoorraadType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('voorraad_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Deletes a Voorraad entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="voorraad_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ToolsForEverVoorraadBundle:Voorraad')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Voorraad entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('voorraad'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Voorraad entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('voorraad_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Verwijder voorraad'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

VoorraadType.php (form)

```
<?php

namespace ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class VoorraadType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('aantal')
        ->add('locatie', 'entity', array (
        'empty_data' => null,
        'label' => 'Kies locatie',
        'class' => 'ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Entity\Locatie',
        'choice_label' => function ($locatie) {
            return $locatie->getLocatienaam();
        }


        ))
        ->add('product', 'entity', array(
        'empty_data' => null,
        'label' => 'Kies product',
        'class' => 'ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Entity\Product',
        'choice_label' => function ($product) {
            return $product->getNaam();
        }
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'ToolsForEver\VoorraadBundle\Entity\Voorraad'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'toolsforever_voorraadbundle_voorraad';
}
}
```

index.html.twig (view)

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
<h1 class="hoofdtitel">Voorraad lijst</h1>

<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th>Id</th> -->
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Fabriek</th>
            <th>Aantal</th>
            <th>Inkoopprijs</th>
            <th>Verkoopprijs
            <th>Locatie</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
    <!--    <td><a href="{{ path('voorraad_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td> -->
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getNaam() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getType() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getFabriek() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.aantal }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getInkoopprijs() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getProduct().getVerkoopprijs() }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.getLocatie().getLocatienaam() }}</td>
            <td>

                    <a href="{{ path('voorraad_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Voorraad aanpassen</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
        <br>
        <a href="{{ path('voorraad_new') }}">
            Nieuwe voorraad toevoegen   
        </a>

{% endblock %}
```

So with a simple code in my controller I managed to get the products ordered by location.

So the last step for me is to use a select box to show the products by location and "remove" the products from the list with a other location. The image below is my result so far, and I want the selectbox above this list. Hope somebody can help me out..

[image: So far..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony Cookbook provides an example of this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Basically, you need to use the `query_builder` property of "entity" fields to restrain your Products based on Location. Then, when the User change the value of Location, create a JS script that will submit the form on an asynchronous side request, get the select box of Products in the response and replace it inside the page. You will need to use EventListeners in your form as well, to dynamically update your fields.

However, I find this solution pretty "heavy" in the end, because you have to go through a whole form submission process just to get your list of Products. To improve this, you may create a Controller Action that would return a list of Products based on Location, and call this route when Location is changed.

But in both cases, AJAX and Form EventListeners are mandatory.

Comment: Alright, So there is no other way to do this? With twig or PHP? unfortunately I am not experienced with AJAX..

Comment: Sorry, as I said it is mandatory. Twig and PHP can only impact on your backend, but right there you want something dynamic in your client's Web browser. So you need to use JavaScript, and you need AJAX to get the list of Products from your server. But it is always time to learn :)

Comment: Haha well, This is the right answer, and Have I alot to learn.. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a call AJAX for calling anothers controller SF that filter your result and response with new JSON data.

If your response AJAX is correct you can move old result and add a new html code formatting with JS for viewing result select box.

**AJAX + controller SF = change result webpage without reloaded this**